# pass function argument down to other function with do.call

Tags: r, environment, do.call

I would like to pass object `met` down to function `sf` but get object not found error. I think it might have to do with the environment of the top function call that it is not passed to the subfunction:

```
f <- function(fname,x,met=c('sum','subs')){

  .env <- environment() ## identify the environment
  do.call(fname,list(x,met),envir=.env)

}

sf <- function(x,...){

  if (met== 'sum') x + 100 else x - 100

}

f('sf',1:10,met='sum')
```

Comment: `f('sf',1:10,met='sum')` gives `[1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110` on my machine and no error message. However, for `met='subs'` the result is the same.

Comment: @PhillipD thanks, I do get the error but in any case G. Grothendieck found where it comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`met` cannot be referred to by name in the body of `sf` if it has not been explicitly passed as an argument of `sf` so try this:

```
sf <- function(x, met, ...) {
  if (met == 'sum') x + 100 else x - 100
}
```

If we assume `met` is the first component of `...` in the call to `sf` (as is the case in the example in the question) then this works too:

```
sf <- function(x, ...) {
  met <- list(...)[[1]]
  if (met == 'sum') x + 100 else x - 100
}
```

And this more concise alternative works too:

```
sf <- function(x, ...) {
  met <- ...[[1]]
  if (met == 'sum') x + 100 else x - 100
}
```

And even more concise is this alternative:

```
sf <- function(x, ...) {
  met <- ..1
  if (met == 'sum') x + 100 else x - 100
}
```

We don't really need the `env` argument to `do.call` here.

UPDATE: Correction.

Comment: I wanted to avoid explicitly passing the argument, the second option works like a charm, many thanks! what `..1` in the third option does?

Comment: `..1` is the first component of `...` .  See `?..1` .